# How to get data with this Json

Tags: android, json

I want to show data of below JSON:

```
{"success":true,"message":"","result":{"Bid":3924.01000000,"Ask":3925.00000000,"Last":3924.00000000}}
```

I am new in android and from all tutorials, I somehow access this data but I want to show only "Last" data figure but my code shows whole "result" string.

```
String firstname;

TextView tv;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);

    new AsyncTaskParseJson().execute();

}


// you can make this class as another java file so it will be separated from your main activity.
public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";

    // set your json string url here
    String yourJsonStringUrl = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=usdt-btc";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;

    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try {

            // instantiate our json parser
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // get json string from url
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);


            firstname = json.getString("result");

            Log.e(TAG, "Last: " + firstname);


        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {

        tv.setText(""+firstname);

    }
}
```

Comment: you are not making any network call. `jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);` is not a way to make a network call. you are just parsing  your url only and hence not getting the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not making a network call. You are just parsing your Url. You need to make network call. You can use volley for this. In your onCreate method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=usdt-btc";

 // Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(String response) {

      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
    try {
        JSONObject result = json.getJSONObject("result");
        Double last = result.getDouble("Last");
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(last));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
 @Override
   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

  }
});
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
 queue.add(stringRequest);


}
```

you need to define internet permission in Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

You need to include volley library for this http request. Include this in build.gradle of your app

```
dependencies {
 .
 .
 compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
 .
 .
}
```

Comment: You are not making a network call, you are just parsing you url only @GauravSharma

Comment: Manifest part already done trying volley now thanks in andvance

Comment: No change Same 0.00.0 Either it is showing the full "result" string or nothing  I only want "Last" Data from Json

Comment: Have you implemented the Volley StringRequest part in your onCreate as mentioned in my answer?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should be able to do this

```
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);
return "" + json.get("result").getDouble("Last");
```

The string is returned from doInBackground to onPostExecute in the strFromDoInBg variable, but if you prefer:

```
firstname = "" + json.get("result").getDouble("Last");
```

would also work

Comment: Not Working sir

Comment: Is {"success":true,"message":"","result":{"Bid":3924.01000000,"Ask":3925.00000000,"Last":3924.00000000}} what you printed from the firstname in your code?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the value of Last was a number. I've updated the answer to get it as a double then convert to string

Comment: I print whole  "result" in first name

Comment: So only :{"Bid":3924.01000000,"‌​Ask":3925.00000000,"‌​Last":3924.00000000}‌ then?

Comment: In that case the .get("result") needs to go

Comment: Earlier it shows null but as i use double it shows 0.00.0

Comment: When I go to the address in you example I get the full JSON you pasted. In that case you still need .get("result") to get the result first, then getDouble("Last") from that object

Comment: @Peter you should know that OP is not making any network calls actually and you are answering to parse the url only and not its response.

Comment: From the comments it says "I print whole "result" in first name" meaning: Yes, getJSONFromUrl was doing a network call and JSON was printed, not the URL